# How to achieve MongoDB aggregate query pipeline stage { $group: {_id: "$$ROOT"} } from springboot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

In my spring-boot project, MongoDB aggregation queries are tailored using different interfaces in org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation package like AggregationOperation, GroupOperation etc. as follows.

```
List<AggregationOperation> aggList = new ArrayList<>();

MatchOperation match = match(//pass filters here...
aggList.add(match);

GroupOperation group = new GroupOperation(...//group fields and aliases
aggList.add(group);

ProjectionOperation projection= project().andExclude("_id");
//append other projections here
...
aggList.add(projection);

Aggregation aggregationOp = Aggregation.newAggregation(aggList);
AggregationResults<Object> aggResults = this.getOperations().aggregate(aggregationOp , collectionName,
                Object.class);
return aggResults.getMappedResults();
```

This is working well so far.
But now I need to add a group with $$ROOT stage (In order to eliminate duplicates) like below.

```
{ $group: { _id: "$$ROOT" } }
```

I have tried different approaches but failed.
The failed approaches are given below.

```
//Approach 1:
aggList.add(Aggregation.group(Aggregation.ROOT));
```

which gives me below error,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference '$$ROOT'!
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.getReference(ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.java:100) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
```

and approach 2,

```
//Approach 2:
aggList.add(new AggregationOperation() {

                    @Override
                    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                        return new Document("$group", 
                                new Document("_id", Aggregation.ROOT));
                    }
                });
```

which gave me below error,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference '_id'!
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.getReference(ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.java:100) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
```

Can anyone help me out?

**ANSWER:**
Below code works!

```
aggList.add(new AggregationOperation() {

                    @Override
                    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                        return new Document("$group", 
                                new Document("_id", "$$ROOT"));
                    }
                });
```

Thank you Varman for help!

Comment: This works in spring-data-mongodb v2.2.2: `GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("$$ROOT")`

Comment: If prasad s solution not working, Just use `$$ROOT` instead of `Aggregation.ROOT` in your second approach, it should work